# WebService InvocationTargetException

Tags: web-services, soap, wildfly

I have 2 SOAP web service applications - Consumer and Producer 
Both running in separate Wildfly instances on my Mac.

- The Wildfly with the Producer is running up in a docker container.
- The Wildfly with the Consumer is running up in a wildfly instance
  running on my Mac.

Now when the Consumer makes a web service call I am encountering the following exception

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
        at com.sample.consumers.RequestMessageConsumer.getResponse(RequestMessageConsumer.java:885) [classes:?]
        at com.sample.services.jms.MessageListener.onMessage(MessageListener.java:106) [classes:?]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:761) [spring-jms-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:699) [spring-jms-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:674) [spring-jms-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:318) [spring-jms-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:245) [spring-jms-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1189) [spring-jms-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1179) [spring-jms-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1076) [spring-jms-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_181]
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Fault occurred while processing.
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:161) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy806.externalDocument(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        ... 18 more
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Fault occurred while processing.
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap12FaultInInterceptor.unmarshalFault(Soap12FaultInInterceptor.java:155) ~[cxf-rt-bindings-soap-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap12FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap12FaultInInterceptor.java:66) ~[cxf-rt-bindings-soap-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap12FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap12FaultInInterceptor.java:52) ~[cxf-rt-bindings-soap-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) ~[cxf-core-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:112) ~[cxf-core-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:69) ~[cxf-rt-bindings-soap-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:34) ~[cxf-rt-bindings-soap-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) ~[cxf-core-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:798) ~[cxf-core-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1670) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1551) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1348) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.io.CacheAndWriteOutputStream.postClose(CacheAndWriteOutputStream.java:56) ~[cxf-core-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStream.close(CachedOutputStream.java:216) ~[cxf-core-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56) ~[cxf-core-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:651) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62) ~[cxf-core-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) ~[cxf-core-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:514) ~[cxf-core-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:423) ~[cxf-core-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:324) ~[cxf-core-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:277) ~[cxf-core-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-simple-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:139) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.1.6.jar:3.1.6]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy806.externalDocument(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        ... 18 more
```

The issue is around :-

```
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Fault occurred while processing.
```

The above stacktrace is from logging of the stackTraceAsString variable - code snippet below

However, there is not much to give an idea of the cause of the failure.

I am able to successfully invoke the Producer web service via SoapUI running on my Mac.

I have checked the endpoint url configured for the Consumer. It is the same as what is used by SoapUI.

Any suggestion to understand the cause and solution would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Pete

**snippet of the code**

```
// get the web service operation to invoke for this request type.
final String webServiceOperation = getRequestOperation();

final Class<ProducerWebServiceInterface> clientProducerWebServiceInterface = ProducerWebServiceInterface.class;

// get the appropriate web service method to invoke
Method method = null;
WebServiceResponse serviceResponse = null;

try {

    method = clientProducerWebServiceInterface.getMethod(webServiceOperation, type);

    serviceResponse = (WebServiceResponse) method.invoke(client, operation);

}

catch (final SecurityException | NoSuchMethodException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException exception) {

        logError ( exception );

}
catch ( final Exception exception ) {

    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(stringWriter);
    exception.printStackTrace(printWriter);
    String stackTraceAsString = stringWriter.toString();

        logError ( exception );

}
```

Seems the line of code

return invoke0(method, obj, args);

in the  NativeMethodAccessorImpl class is throwing the InvocationTargetException but still no idea what the cause. 
The params - method, obj, args - all look ok.
I identified this by setting a break point in eclipse to break at the InvocationTargetException occurance.

```
class NativeMethodAccessorImpl extends MethodAccessorImpl {
    private final Method method;
    private DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl parent;
    private int numInvocations;

    NativeMethodAccessorImpl(Method method) {
        this.method = method;
    }

    public Object invoke(Object obj, Object[] args)
        throws IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException
    {
        // We can't inflate methods belonging to vm-anonymous classes because
        // that kind of class can't be referred to by name, hence can't be
        // found from the generated bytecode.
        if (++numInvocations > ReflectionFactory.inflationThreshold()
                && !ReflectUtil.isVMAnonymousClass(method.getDeclaringClass())) {
            MethodAccessorImpl acc = (MethodAccessorImpl)
                new MethodAccessorGenerator().
                    generateMethod(method.getDeclaringClass(),
                                   method.getName(),
                                   method.getParameterTypes(),
                                   method.getReturnType(),
                                   method.getExceptionTypes(),
                                   method.getModifiers());
            parent.setDelegate(acc);
        }

        return invoke0(method, obj, args);
```

Comment: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException comes from the handler function you have written for this call. There was an error over there, which you might not have logged and printed.

Comment: Updated to include a code snippet and to show how the I have generated the stack trace.
Do you think the error logging is missing something out ?

Comment: method.invoke(client, operation); - The method being invoked here is throwing the error. So whats wrong there?

Comment: I am using java.lang.reflect.Method and reflection to invoke the web service.
This approach has been successfully used in other projects and so I am re using the approach.
As to why method.invoke(client, operation);  is throwing the exception I guess is what is the missing information and not sure how to determine. I thought the stack trace would give this information. Sadly setting LOG LEVEL to DEBUG for org.apache package does not appear to work and therefore additional information is not logged,

Comment: Nope, Reflection is fine, but the method you invoked expected something - which turned to be bad. Find that. !

Comment: ok I need to pop out for 30 or so mins and will see if I can spot anything... shame the log is not able to give more pointers

Comment: updated above query to show possibly where the exception is raised ie Seems the line of code 

return invoke0(method, obj, args);

in the  NativeMethodAccessorImpl class is throwing the InvocationTargetException but still no idea what the cause. 
The params - method, obj, args - all look ok.
I identified this by setting a break point in eclipse to break at the InvocationTargetException occurance.

Comment: I was talking about the class where method was implemented. There will be a method with name same as webServiceOperation , in a class. One more question what is ProducerWebServiceInterface ?

Comment: Hi Kris. Apologises for the late response. Finally resolved the issue. More embarrassingly, it was my fault. In the application build, I had accidently omitted the cxf.xml file.  I assume as a result, Apache Cxf  didn't know how to cater for the Web Service call and hence the InvocationTargetException. Once the cxf.xml file was introduced, was able to make the web service call. Thank you for your help. Pete