# Soap-UI 5.4.0 Mock Service

Tags: soapui

- I am having trouble with configuring a mock web service using SoapUI
  5.4.0.

  I am trying to investigate why my Consumer is not able to make a web
  service call to a Producer.

  I have raised this as a separate question 
  [WebService InvocationTargetException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60700938/webservice-invocationtargetexception)

I feel like I have configured the SoapUI Mock Service correctly.

When the Consumer invokes the mock web service, the following exception is report by the Consumer application :-

```
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Response was of unexpected text/html ContentType.  Incoming portion of HTML stream: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap:Body>
    <soap:Fault>
      <soap:Code>
        <soap:Value>Server</soap:Value>
      </soap:Code>
      <soap:Reason>
        <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
        <soap:Text xml:lang="en">java.lang.NullPointerException</soap:Text>
      </soap:Reason>
    </soap:Fault>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:161)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy698.getDocument(Unknown Source)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Response was of unexpected text/html ContentType.  Incoming portion of HTML stream: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap:Body>
    <soap:Fault>
      <soap:Code>
        <soap:Value>Server</soap:Value>
      </soap:Code>
      <soap:Reason>
        <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
        <soap:Text xml:lang="en">java.lang.NullPointerException</soap:Text>
      </soap:Reason>
    </soap:Fault>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Nothing is reported in SoapUI ie request received or error returned.

Whilst I think, I have configured SoapUI correctly, it seems there may be some additional configuration that I may need to do.

Any suggestions or pointers to tutorial/youtube video please

Thank you in advance

Pete